# How to create a shell script which can create a .java file on executing?

Tags: linux, bash

The requirement is to create a shell script that can create a `FileName.java` file where `FileName` would be the parameter passed to the script while running the script.

**Example:**

```
$ ./shellscript.sh Sample
```

On executing the above command, a file `Sample.java` should get created with content:

```
class Sample{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      System.out.println("Hello World !!!"); 
   }
}
```

*If sources for learning bash scripting is added in the answer it would be very helpful.*

Comment: See: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: Thank you @stark, will definitely check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here-docs will expand variables, so

```
NAME=$1
cat << EOF > $NAME.java
class $NAME{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      System.out.println("Hello World !!!"); 
   }
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a "template", something like:

**classTemplate.txt**

```
class #ClassName{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      System.out.println("Hello World !!!"); 
   }
}
```

After that, you just need to replace **#ClassName** with your parameter

```
#create .java file
cp classTemplate.txt classTemplate.java 
#set class name
sed -i 's/#ClassName/MyClass/g' classTemplate.java
```

Answer (score 0):

The following book is a good reference:

[https://www.amazon.com/Bash-Pocket-Reference-Power-Admins/dp/1491941596](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491941596)

I would just continue to use stackoverflow and google. This is what has helped me most, since I can search for specific solutions to what I am trying to do. In stackoverflow, you can also run your code and proposed solution by other people and find improved solutions. This is extremely valuable.